# Code giving me an ArgumentExeption?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, windows-phone-8

This code is giving me an ArgumentExeption when the correct values are put in both ComboBoxes, executing the code. The code basically just deletes a file and replaces it with a modified version taken from another folder.

Here is the exact text of the error message:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: The given file path ends with a directory separator character.

Here's the code:

```
 If ComboBox1.Text = "Nokia" And ComboBox2.Text = "HTC" And My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Users\" + user + "\Documents\Fiddler2\Scripts\CustomRules.js") Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Users\" + user + "\Documents\Fiddler2\Scripts\CustomRules.js")
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("Config\OEM\NokiaHTC.js", destinationFileName:="C:\Users\" + user + "\Documents\Fiddler2\Scripts\")
        Else
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("Config\OEM\NokiaHTC.js", destinationFileName:="C:\Users\" + user + "\Documents\Fiddler2\Scripts\")
        End If
```

Comment: What message is included in the argument exception?

Comment: System.ArgumentException: The given file path ends with a directory separator character.
Parameter name: destinationFileName

Comment: Well have you tried taking the obvious action and removing the directory separator character from the destination filename?

Comment: Yes, and it simply errors out again, this time with another error, but I know what it means and fixed it.

Comment: Please review [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36xbexyf(v=vs.90).aspx) for the CopyFile method.  The second parameter is not a folder name, but a file name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the destination file path ends with a `"\"` value.  This isn't legal for the `CopyFile` API.  Switch it to include the file name and this should fix the problem

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile( _
  "Config\OEM\NokiaHTC.js", _
  destinationFileName:="C:\Users\" + user + "\Documents\Fiddler2\Scripts\NokiaHTC.js")
```